# Instantiate a priority queue with a comparator from spring

Tags: java, spring, priority-queue, comparator

As part of learning spring, I'm trying to declare a priority queue bean of MyMessageObject objects, but keep getting the following BeanCreationException: "Error creating bean with name 'messagesHeap' defined in URL [file:/my.app.spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor"

Here's my spring definitions:

```
<bean id="messagesHeap" class="java.util.PriorityQueue">
    <constructor-arg type="int" name="initialCapacity" value="100" index="0"/>
    <constructor-arg name="comparator" type="java.util.Comparator" index="1"  ref="orderComparator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="orderComparator" class="com.my.myComparator"/>
```

The class *myComparator* implements java.util.Comparator as required.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<bean id="messagesHeap" class="java.util.PriorityQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="100" />
    <constructor-arg ref="orderComparator" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you explain why omitting the <i>name</i> attribute solves the problem?

Comment: spring docs: This requires debug symbols to be 
 stored in the class file in order to introspect argument names!